# Deserialize Json with special character into dictionary

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I got some trouble with a problem when use Newtonsoft json.net to deserialize json string to dictionary. It 's a case of my json string have some special character.

```
string jsonString = "{\"name\":\"Jones Smith\",\"age\":\"20\",\"description\":\"The one live with \"ALIGATOR\"\"}";
Dictionary<string, object> dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonString);
```

I try to find a solution in the use of json.net but i not found. So the FINAL plan is remove that "characters". So, what is the best solution for this case?

Comment: That string is not valid JSON `\"ALIGATOR\"` should really be `\\\"ALIGATOR\\\"`

Comment: You can confirm that your JSON string is not well-formed by uploading to https://jsonlint.com/.  (Don't forget to upload the actual raw string not the c# literal with escaping.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do very much in your situation besides changing the format at the origin. The problem with your input is that there are `"` characters escaped the same way once in your json directly and once in your json values.

Consider the following part: `"description":"The one live with "ALIGATOR""`
How should a deserializer know which `"` should be considered part of the value or part of the json format?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, like the last comment, that 's not valid JSON, below is valid JSON

```
{"name":"Jones Smith","age":"20","description":"The one live with \"ALIGATOR\""}
```

And all i can do is add '\' before special characters if the value of field description is "The one live with "ALIGATOR"" to make a valid JSON and convert to c# like this:

```
string jsonString = {\"name\":\"Jones Smith\",\"age\":\"20\",\"description\":\"The one live with \\"ALIGATOR\\"\"}
```